# use openweathermap with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to give out data from openweathermap  with PHP.I already have a code and it works perfectly. But if i want to add a weather description or Icon an then open the site it won't work. The error is : **"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wetter\wetter.php on line 40"**.Here is my code :

```
if(isset($city)) {
$url = 'http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/name?q='.urlencode($city).'&cnt=1&lang=de';

$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$data = json_decode($json);

if(!empty($data->list[0]->name)) {
?>
<div>
   Stadt: <strong><?php echo $data->list[0]->name ?></strong><br />
   Aktuell:<strong><?php echo number_format($data->list[0]->main->temp - 273.15, 1, ',', '') ?> &deg; C </strong><br />
   Temperatur (heute):  <br />
   min. <?php echo number_format($data->list[0]->main->temp_min - 273.15, 1, ',', '') ?> &deg; C<br />
   max. <?php echo number_format($data->list[0]->main->temp_max - 273.15, 1, ',', '') ?> &deg; C<br />
   Luftfeuchtigkeit: <?php echo number_format($data->list[0]->main->humidity)?> %<br />
   Windgeschwindigkeit: <?php echo $data->list[0]->wind->speed ?>m/s<br />
   Windrichtung: <?php echo $data->list[0]->wind->deg ?>&deg;<br />
   Wolken: <?php echo $data->list[0]->clouds->all ?>%<br />
   <b>Wetter: <?php echo $data->list[0]->weather->description ?><b><br />
</div>
```

output of var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (7) { ["message"]=> string(0) "" ["cod"]=> string(3) "200" ["type"]=> string(4) "base" ["calctime"]=> string(0) "" ["units"]=> string(8) "internal" ["count"]=> int(1) ["list"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (11) { ["id"]=> int(0) ["coord"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["lat"]=> float(47.366669) ["lon"]=> float(8.55) } ["name"]=> string(6) "Zurich" ["main"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (5) { ["temp"]=> float(282.71) ["pressure"]=> int(1021) ["humidity"]=> int(76) ["temp_min"]=> float(280.93) ["temp_max"]=> float(284.82) } ["dt"]=> int(1462265876) ["date"]=> string(19) "2016-05-03 08:57:56" ["wind"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (2) { ["speed"]=> int(1) ["deg"]=> int(0) } ["clouds"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) { ["all"]=> int(40) } ["weather"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4) { ["id"]=> int(802) ["main"]=> string(6) "Clouds" ["description"]=> string(16) "scattered clouds" ["icon"]=> string(3) "03d" } } ["sys"]=> object(stdClass)#8 (1) { ["population"]=> int(0) } ["url"]=> string(31) "http://openweathermap.org/city/" } } }
```

Comment: Could you highlight line 40 in your code?

Comment: i'cant Highlight it so here-> <b>Wetter: <?php echo $data->list[0]->weather->description ?><b><br />

Comment: Do a var_dump on $data and post the output.

Comment: it's in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data->list[0]->weather[0]->description
```

Not tested, but this might be the correct code. The data inside "weather" is an array which you have to address first before you can get the data of "description".

Answer (score 1):

`weather` is an array so you should do something like this to access `description` property:

```
<b>Wetter: <?php echo $data->list[0]->weather[0]['description'] ?><b><br />
```